# How can I count items from purchase price?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am stuck trying to write a `mysql` query.  The requirement is to count the number of `white` and `red` items, which I can purchase for a total $20 price.  Here is my attempted query:

```
SELECT colour, purchasePrice
FROM `product`
```

It returns this result [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi736.png).
But, I want to count how many `white` and `red` items are in the $20 price.  For example, imagine I have a budget of $20, and each item costs $2.00.  Therefore, I know I can only buy 10 of them.
I hope this is easy to understand.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You have multiple prices for red and white are you always buying at lowest price?

Comment: Please tag the version of MySQL you are using

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for response ,if i check with `20 budget` then expected output may be like this `White     10 items` for white items

Comment: @P.Salmon i want to count number of items in budget

Comment: @JohnHC yes i am using `mysql`, i want query in `MySQL`

Comment: 'i want to count number of items in budget'   based on lowest price for item in product?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes,,please provide me both for highest to lowest and lowest to highest,

Comment: Imagine I have a budget of $20 , and the item costs 2.00, I know I can only buy 10 of them. Hope understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL 8.0 onwards, there are Window Functions to create a cumulative price for the colours permitted:

```
select count(*) -- counts the number of items
from
(
select sum(p1.purchasePrice) over (order by p1.purchasePrice asc) as c_price -- Our cumulative price
from product p1
where colour in ('white', 'red') -- limit the colours
) x2
where  x2.c_price <= 20 -- where the cumulative is less than the budget
```

---

EDIT:
It seems you are looking for how many of each item you can buy, rather than how many from the list:

```
select colour, purchasePrice,
       floor(20/purchasePrice) as qty_for_20 -- floor rounds the number down
from products
where colour in ('white', 'red')
```

Comment: `select colour, purchasePrice,
       floor(purchasePrice / 20) as qty_for_20 -- floor rounds the number down
from products
where colour in ('white', '
red')` Give me `EMPTY` record

Comment: @icon It looks like you are using an earlier version. The empty rows should be fixed by my edit.

Comment: thankssssssssssssssssssssssssss working great :) @JohnHC